# Comply with domain proof of ownership requirements

Tags: oauth, google-calendar-api

My website is a service site, it is separated with Parent company website
I want to use GG calendar API, so i access to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis to set required link.
But after that, i received below email.
I did not create a privacy policy page (because it's involved to with Parent company website).
Can i use privacy policy page on Parent companies'website to reference?

Please note that Google API Service:User Data Policy requires the following:

Your Privacy policy must be visible to users, hosted within the domain of your website, and linked to the OAuth Consent Screen on APIs & Services
on Google Cloud Console.

Your privacy policy and in-product privacy notifications must thoroughly disclose the manner in which your application accesses, uses, stores, or shares Google user data. Your use of Google user data must be limited to the practices explicitly disclosed in your published privacy policy.

Please make appropriate changes to the privacy policy and/or your app and reply back to us to move forward with the approval process.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up the OAuth 2.0 consent screen for your app, it will look something similar to this:

[image]

If you look closely, the 4th element is represented by the app's *privacy policy*.

Therefore, if you have the necessary access and permissions in order to use them for your own application, it shouldn't be a problem in this sense.

Moreover, since you mentioned you are making use of the Calendar API, you might want to check the **Sensitive and restricted scopes** of this article [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914).

#### Reference

- [OAuth API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914).